# How to skip validation of the header while submitting a form containing table?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-table

I have a form and there is a table in it. I am doing something like

```
function validate(){
var result = true;
$("tr").each(function(){

    if($(this).find(".qty").val()<1||isNaN($(this).find(".qty").val())){
        result = false;
        return false;
    }
    if($(this).find(".pvDetails").text()==""){
         result = false;
         return false;
    }
});

if(result)
    return true;
else
    alert('correct the input values | check your ID or Qty field');
return false;

}
```

But this will also take my header for validation as my header is defined as below -

```
<tr height="50px" bgcolor="#EEE8CD">
                    <th align="left" width="10%">Serial No.</th>
                    <th align="left" width="15%">Variant ID</th>
                    <th align="left" width="20%">Product Detail</th>
                    <th align="left" width="17%">Product Image</th>
                    <th align="left" width="10%">B2B Price</th>
                    <th align="left" width="13%">Quantity</th>
                    <th align="left" width="12%">Total</th>
                </tr>
```

and rest is my table body.

How do I skip the validation of my table header while using the same approach as I am taking.

Answer (score 1):

I think the tag name of your headers are only `<th>` and your table content cells are `<td>` so the basic idea would be checking the tag name of the children of your `<tr>`

```
   $("tr").children().each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop("tagName") == "td") {
        if ($(this).find(".qty").val() < 1 || !isNaN($(this).find(".qty").val())) {
            result = false;
            return false;
        }
        if ($(this).find(".pvDetails").text() == "") {
            result = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
   });
```

well the another idea is just reading only on the `<tbody>` section just like this

```
$("#mytable tbody tr").children().each(function () {

        if ($(this).find(".qty").val() < 1 || !isNaN($(this).find(".qty").val())) {
            result = false;
            return false;
        }
        if ($(this).find(".pvDetails").text() == "") {
            result = false;
            return false;
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a classname of 'skipvalidation' to any rows you don't want to be validated. Then modify the 3rd line to be like this:

```
$("tr").not('.skipvalidation').each(function(){ ...
```

Comment: that's one way. another way would be to use a `thead` for the header row and a `tbody` for the rest of the table, and the initial selector should be $("tr", "tbody") or any other selector combination possible.